# Keyboard covering textfield on modalsheet

Tags: flutter

im having issues with my keyboard not going up  inside of a modalsheet. so my plan was to open a modalsheet where i could see comments from multiple users then they would be able to scroll down the screen for even more comemnts, but at the bottom there always need to be a textfield so they can comment, the issue is the no matter what the keybaord keeps ignoring the content below

This is the code for the textfield and the container.

```
class CommentTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const CommentTextField({
    super.key, required this.function,
  });

 final Function() function;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Neumorphic(
        style:  NeumorphicStyle(
          boxShape: NeumorphicBoxShape.rect(),
      color: Color(0xff232222),
      shadowDarkColor: Colors.black,
      shadowLightColor: Colors.black,
      depth: 3,
      lightSource: LightSource.bottom),
      child: Container(
        width: double.maxFinite,
        height: ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, 7),
        child: Row(children: [
          _TextField(textEditingController: textEditingController),
          NeumorphicButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            onPressed: () {
              
            },
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context,3)),
            style: NeumorphicStyle(
              boxShape: NeumorphicBoxShape.circle(),
              color: ggrushTheme.colorScheme.primary,
              depth: 3,
              shadowDarkColor: Colors.black,
              shadowLightColor: Color.fromARGB(0, 239, 237, 237),
              lightSource: LightSource.top),
              
              child: Container(
                width: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, 9),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                child: Image.asset('assets/icons/Rocket_Launch.png'),
              ),
          )
        ],),
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _TextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const _TextField({
    super.key, 
    required this.textEditingController,
  });

  final TextEditingController textEditingController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, 4)),
      height: ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, 4),
      width: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, 81),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, 3)),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xff252525),
        border: Border.all(width: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, .2),color: Color.fromARGB(255, 32, 32, 32)),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none
        ),
        cursorHeight: ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, 4),
        controller: textEditingController,
        maxLines: 1,
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the one with stack,

````
class CommentsColumn extends StatelessWidget {
  const CommentsColumn({
    super.key,


  });


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: ScrollController(),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [        
           Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
             children: [
               Image.asset('assets/icons/comments.png', height: ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, 2.5)),
               HorizontalSpace(width: 2,),
               AutoSizeText('82', style: ggrushTheme.textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(fontSize: 14),)]),
               VerticalSpace(height: 4),
            Column(
              children: [
                CommentContainer(comment: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa8we ', username: 'Arisbor',image: ''),
                CommentContainer(comment: 'me gusta mucho este higlight siento que esta muy bueno!', username: 'Wolf',image: ''),
                CommentContainer(comment: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', username: 'Arisbor',image: ''),
                CommentContainer(comment: 'me gusta mucho este higlight siento que esta muy bueno!', username: 'Wolf',image: ''),
              ]),
            VerticalSpace(height: 6,)])
            ),
        CommentTextField(function: () {
          
        },)

      ],
    );
  }
}```



I tried to put a container with the size of the screen and a singlechildscrollview over it, i tried an attachable keyboard package, the scaffold fix doesnt work with this since its a modalsheet, and nothing works, i think the keyboard is not considering the stuff behind it, i have checked multiple posts.
````